# SoftAssert assertion Statements getting appended and few assertions are giving wrong results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

The Assertion results are not so good. They are getting appended for each assertions followed after the 1st Assertion statement.
The sa.assertAll should fail the test method as ONLY Test2 & Test5 assertions should pass and rest all should fail with correct print statements in console. But with my code, the statements are getting appended.

AssertionDemo Image:
[image: AssertionDemo Image]

Print Statements in Console:
[image: Print Statements in Console]

```
 package com.roughwork;

import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class AssertionDemo {
    
    
    SoftAssert sa;
    
    public AssertionDemo(SoftAssert sa) {
        this.sa = sa;
    }
    
    public void assertTrue(boolean condition, String msg) {
        //sa = new SoftAssert();
        
        try {
            sa.assertTrue(condition);
            sa.assertAll();
            System.out.println(msg);
            
        }catch(AssertionError ae) {
            System.out.println("Assertion Failed: "+msg+ "\n" +ae.getLocalizedMessage());
            
        }   
    }
    
    public void assertEquals(Object actual, Object expected, String msg) {
        //sa = new SoftAssert();
        
        try {
            sa.assertEquals(actual, expected);
            sa.assertAll();
            System.out.println(msg);    
        }catch(AssertionError ae) {
            System.out.println("Assertion Failed: "+msg+ "\n" +ae.getLocalizedMessage());   
        }   
    }
    
    public SoftAssert getTheAssertObj() {
        return sa;
    }

}
```

---

```
AssertionExample.java 

package com.roughwork;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class AssertionExample {
    
    AssertionDemo ademo;
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Before Class Method is executed");
    }

    @Test
    public void f() {
        SoftAssert sa = new SoftAssert();
        ademo = new AssertionDemo(sa);
        
        ademo.assertEquals(true, false, "Test1");
        ademo.assertEquals(false, false, "Test2");
        ademo.assertTrue('a'=='b', "Test3");
        ademo.assertEquals(5, 6, "Test4");
        ademo.assertEquals("Mayank", "Mayank", "Test5");
        
        ademo.getTheAssertObj().assertAll();
        
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("After Class Method is executed");
    }

}
```